# Case where reCaptcha v3 won't block bots

Tags: bots, recaptcha

I was having huge card testing bots issues on a website using Stripe.
I had to close the payment part for a while to find the solution.
I had reCaptcha setup by a freelancer. All seems good, the reliability score is set up to 0.9, yet I still got bots making accounts on my service.

In which case bots would be able to pass through reCaptcha v3 and how am I suppose to stop them if this captcha is not working ? It is a very small business I don't have the funds to buy an enterprise solution.

Thank you for enlightments.

EDIT :

Here's the part of the code that handles captcha verification :

```
//captcha verification
if(!request.v) return error(401, "Error");
console.log("Captcha tracking, ", "start")
var captchaResp = await fetch(
    "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=SECRETKEY&response=" + request.v + "&remoteip=" + event.requestContext.identity.sourceIp);
const captchaRespJson = await captchaResp.json();
console.log("Captcha tracking, ", captchaRespJson)
if (!(captchaRespJson.success==true && captchaRespJson.score >= 0.9)) {
    console.log("Captcha tracking, ", "error")
    firebase.auth().deleteUser(decodedToken.uid);
    return error(401, "Error");
}
console.log("Captcha tracking, ", "all done")
//end captcha verification
```

The developper also added a honeypot. But it seems that I still get bots registering and getting access to Stripe checkout, with disposable emails domain names. Now it's been online since this afternoon, so maybe I need to wait for reCaptcha to get more data about my website ? I didn't put the reCaptcha snippet on every page but only on the two more visited pages.

Comment: `Thank you for enlightments.` As Confucius once said; `those who seek enlightenment must first share their code and their errors so others may help` - to which end, please provide a [mre] (Confucius may or may not have said that, but let's assume he did!)

Comment: Thank you for your comment :) I'm not sure you could reproduce that precisely, so I'm not sure what code I could share.